# bootstrapping standard errors for a VAR model

Tags: time-series, t-test, bootstrap, vector-autoregression

I am using resampling with replacement from the residuals are a VAR model in order to estimate standard errors of the parameters of the model. The distribution of the parameters for the model do not appear to be normal. My question, then, is how does one construct t-statistics in this case?

It does not appear that the parameter estimates converge to normality, at least not with 10 thousand samples. Should I try for larger sample sizes? Or is there a way to construct a t-statistic with non-normal bootstrap distribution of parameters?